# C programming open() call path

Tags: c

Just having a tiny issue with the C open() system call regarding the filepath, on Linux (Ubuntu).

If I put the absolute path ie open("/home/bob/Desktop/folder/file", O_RDONLY); it opens fine

But say if I run my program on another computer that filepath would not be correct ie username may not be bob

So, when I try open("./Desktop/folder/file", O_RDONLY); the file wont open, is this correct way. I know (~/) wont work but not sure why (./) wont work?

Any suggestions please?

Thanks,

Comment: How are you running your program?  Where are you running it from?

Comment: Try `perror` after your `open` fails: `if (open(...) == -1) perror(...);`

Comment: Thanks guys but I managed to solve in the simplest way. I just moved the folder I want in the open() into my current working folder where my c complied exe is and used (./) and it works fine now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `"./Desktop/folder/file"` it begin the lookup in the current working directory. So it depends on the directory from which the program is launched. So if the current working directory is not `$HOME` the path will not be the same as `~/Desktop/folder/file`.

You can use the `getenv` function to get the value of the `HOME` environment variable, and then build the complete path.

```
char* home = getenv("HOME");
if (home == NULL) goto error;

char* path = "/Desktop/folder/file"
size_t len = strlen(home) + strlen(path) + 1;
char* fullpath = malloc(len);
if (fullpath == NULL) goto error;

strcpy(fullpath, home);
strcat(fullpath, path);

int fd = open(fullpath, O_RDONLY);
free(fullpath);
```

Comment: You should check for malloc failure, your strncpy and strncat argument order is incorrect, and it's really not advisable to ever use strncpy, which unnecessarily zero-pads and *doesn't* necessarily insert the required NUL. And your strncat usage wouldn't prevent buffer overflow if it were an issue. Since the malloc is sized to fit, there's no problem using strcpy and strcat, or simply `sprintf(fullpath, "%s%s", home, path)`.

Comment: @Jim: I've updated the code to check for malloc failure, and to use `strcpy` / `strcat`. I should know it: "Never post code you didn't compile." Thank you.

Comment: Thanks guys but I managed to solve this easy than this. I just moved the folder I want in the open() into my current working folder where my c complied exe is and used (./) and it works fine now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `getenv("HOME")` to get the absolute pathname to your home directory, then construct the rest (the relative part) of the pathname after that.

Also note that it's very rude practice to ever use fixed filenames under the user's home directory except for hidden files/directories (ones beginning with a dot).